# Object in jquery not set on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I would like to get inputs values of a form and place in an object (for an offer).

So i tried to place this code on submit :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#formOffre').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(Offre); // give undefined in console
        if ( typeof Offre == 'undefined'){
            // if undefined, create object
            var Offre = {
                BuyerID: 1, //I will handle this later
                Total: 0,
                OffreItem: [] //array with json objects
            };
            Offre.OffreItem.id = 0;
            console.log("object created");

            for (i=0; i > Offre.OffreItem.id ; i++) {
                Offre.OffreItem.modele = formOffre.modele.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.longueur = formOffre.longueur.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.hauteur = formOffre.hauteur.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.qte = formOffre.qte.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.rix = formOffre.prix.value;
                console.log("getting parameters of inputs to offer");
            }
        } else {
            //if object exists ony get informations of inputs
           Offre.OffreItem.id = 0; 
            for (i=0; Offre.OffreItem.id < i; i++){
                Offre.OffreItem.modele = formOffre.modele.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.longueur = formOffre.longueur.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.hauteur = formOffre.hauteur.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.qte = formOffre.qte.value;
                Offre.OffreItem.rix = formOffre.prix.value;
            }
        }
```

this is my code. when i click on submit for the first time, it go to the if statement and create the object. But when i click again, I go through the if statement like the object is not set.

i put a console log and in every case the object is undefined.

Can you someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: You need to define `Offre` outside of the scope of the function if you want it to be accessible the next time the same function is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking Offre out side of scope in which it is defined .

```
enter coconsole.log(Offre); // give undefined in console
    if ( typeof Offre == 'undefined'){
        // if undefined, create object
        var Offre = { //here is issue this should be above submit function 
            BuyerID: 1, //I will handle this later
            Total: 0,
            OffreItem: [] //array with json objects
        };
```

Also make sure your page is maintaining state.
For you I have created example give a look. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/NaumanKhan/ct7461qf/13/)
Hoping this will solve your problem.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NaumanKhan/ct7461qf/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're defining your variable inside the function.

To simplify your code:

```
$('#formOffre').on('submit', function(e) {
  if ( typeof Offre == 'undefined'){
    var Offre = { }; // This variable is only accessible inside this function
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```

The `var Offre` will define a variable within the scope of the function, the next time you run the function, a new variable with that name will be created (Meaning it will always be `undefined` initially)

To get around this, you can define your variable outside of the function:

```
var Offre;
$('#formOffre').on('submit', function(e) {
  if ( typeof Offre == 'undefined'){
    Offre = { }; // Notice that we're not creating a new variable here, just accessing the one defined above
  } else {
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: 0


thank you for your fast answer.

but i get the same issue

Comment: @Daniel Could you show your updated code in a snippet? This should have worked, did you remove the `var` from the `Offre` inside the function?